# Working with an Affine Variety and Maps

Tags: algebraic-geometry

We have a $\phi :\mathbb C^4 \rightarrow\mathbb C^4$ 
$$\phi (a_1,a_2:b_1,b_2) =
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a_1b_1 & a_1b_2 \\
a_2b_1 & a_2b_2
\end{array}\right)
$$
We want to argue there exists a polynomial in four variables such that $\phi (\mathbb C^4) = V(f)$
then talk about $V(f)$ can be parametrized.
I am sorry I have no idea, probably because I cannot think of a polynomial that when we plug in the matrix we get zero. I would appreciate a hint in the right direction. Thank you so much

Comment: Hint: Segre embedding.

Comment: @Kori: , I tried to edit and still could not figure out what you intended to write. Can you look at this and improve the LaTeX coding, and use underscores for subscripts.

Comment: That is what I intended thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't plug the matrix in the polynomial, rather the entries of the matrix.

How about the polynomial $z_{11} z_{22} - z_{12} z_{21}$?

**Edit**

The map $\phi$ "outputs" $2 \times 2$ matrices. But the vector space of such matrices is isomorphic to the vector space of $4 \times 1$ vectors. These can be thought of as points of $\mathbb{C}^4$.

Comment: Interesting and it does make sense, but please explain to me I thought the map $\phi$ outputs matrices

Comment: @Kori: Does my edit make sense to you?

Comment: Yes, this is very good! I feel helped ha ha, I will work on the parametrization.

Comment: @Kori: Glad i helped!

Comment: I tried this as a parametrization W be the affine variety parametrized by $(t^2,t,t^4,t^3)$ inspired by the fact that $t^2t^3-tt^4=0$ , thus I claimed that $V(f) = W$ , does this seem alright ?